# How to replace a form with a component after submit

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm always unsure when to use the useEffect hook in react, is a situation where it should be used?

I have a simple form and want to replace the form with a message after the submit button has been clicked

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import SubscribeMessage from "./SubscribeMessage";

export default function App() {
  const subscribeHandeler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return <SubscribeMessage />;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Email Subscription</h1>
      <form onSubmit={subscribeHandeler}>
        <div className="subscribeHeader">
          Subscribe to stay tuned for our latest news and updates.
        </div>
        <input
          className="inputEmail"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email address"
        />
        <button className="subscribeBtn">SIGN UP</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working codesandbox can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-shadow-8rbdd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `show` state and update that state on `subscribeHandeler` to display component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import SubscribeMessage from "./SubscribeMessage";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const subscribeHandeler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Email Subscription</h1>
      {!show && (
        <form onSubmit={subscribeHandeler}>
          <div className="subscribeHeader">
            Subscribe to stay tuned for our latest news and updates.
          </div>
          <input
            className="inputEmail"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
          />
          <button className="subscribeBtn">SIGN UP</button>
        </form>
      )}
      {show && <SubscribeMessage />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check here [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-cloud-zi5t9)

Comment: Perfect thank you so much, cannot accept this answer for another 5 minutes but this has solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import SubscribeMessage from "./SubscribeMessage";

export default function App() {
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)

  const subscribeHandeler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitted(true) 
    // handle subscription logic   
  };

  if (submitted) {
    return <SubscribeMessage />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Email Subscription</h1>
      <form onSubmit={subscribeHandeler}>
        <div className="subscribeHeader">
          Subscribe to stay tuned for our latest news and updates.
        </div>
        <input
          className="inputEmail"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Email address"
        />
        <button className="subscribeBtn">SIGN UP</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag that would be toggled based on your submission. And while you render it, render it conditionally based on the flag

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import SubscribeMessage from "./SubscribeMessage";

export default function App() {
  const [submit, setSubmit] = useState(false);

  const subscribeHandeler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmit(!submit);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Email Subscription</h1>
      {!submit ? (
        <form onSubmit={subscribeHandeler}>
          <div className="subscribeHeader">
            Subscribe to stay tuned for our latest news and updates.
          </div>
          <input
            className="inputEmail"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
          />
          <button className="subscribeBtn">SIGN UP</button>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <SubscribeMessage />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```